# How can I specify the scale parameter of the wavelet in PyWavelets (pywt)?

Tags: wavelet, python

When computing wavelet transforms with [PyWavelets](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/) (Discrete Wavelet Transform in Python), e.g.

```
import pywt
cA, cD = pywt.dwt([1, 2, 3, 4], 'db1')

>> print 'cA', cA
cA [ 2.12132034  4.94974747]

>> print 'cD', cD
cD [-0.70710678 -0.70710678]
```

how can I specify the scale parameter of the wavelet?

In Matlab for example using [`cwt()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwt.html) I can specify the scale(s) I want in the parameters, and it will return all possible shifts:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
scales = [1, 2, 3];
wavelet_name = 'db1';
coefs = cwt(x,scales, wavelet_name);

>> coefs =   

   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000
   -0.7071   -0.7071   -0.7071   -0.7071
   -1.1553   -1.1553   -1.1553    1.7371
```

(I'm basically trying to find an equivalent of Matlab's `cwt()` in Python with a decent amount of wavelet functions available unlike `scipy.signal.cwt`.)

Comment: What does cwt() in matlab have that you can't find in scipy.signal.cwt?

You can't specify a scale for the discrete wavelet transform. It has a built-in scale.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks. Here is the issue I have with Scipy: [Where can I see the list of built-in wavelet functions that I can pass to scipy.signal.cwt?](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/16318/1632)

Comment: @Aaron Also, why has the discrete wavelet transform a  built-in scale. Wikipedia seems to say that
[discrete wavelet transforms has discrete shift and scale parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet#Discrete_wavelet_transforms_.28discrete_shift_and_scale_parameters.29) (unlike continuous wavelet transforms, which has continuous shift and scale parameters). I'm learning about wavelets so I might have a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: @Aaron http://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_difference_between_the_2D_continuous_and_discrete_gabor_filter_when_it_comes_to_MATLAB_implementation agrees with you "Unlike the discrete wavelet transform, the continuous wavelet transform CWT can operate at every scale, from that of the original signal up to some maximum scale that you determine by trading off your need for detailed analysis with available computational horsepower.
The CWT is also continuous in terms of shifting: during computation, the analyzing wavelet is shifted smoothly over the full domain of the analyzed function."

Comment: DWT cuts the spectrum in half at each step. So it is possible to narrow in on the scale you want but it is not as flexible as the CWT.